# How to uninstall a software when it is not available in the software store?

Tags: software-center

I tried to install Free File Sync to my Ubuntu 18.04. I came across multiple error messages in the terminal. Now I am left with 3 Free File Sync icons in my apps. None of them work. But they are not available in the software centre to be uninstalled. The terminal commands to are not responsive. Please help me to get rid of the Free File Sync items

Comment: How to uninstall software depends entirely upon how you originally installed it. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1191625/edit) your question to clearly explain where you got Free File Sync from, and exactly how you installed it. A link to any instructions you followed would be particularly helpful.

Comment: Looks like it is a tar.gz from https://freefilesync.org/download.php   Is there an `uninstall.sh` file in the package?

Comment: @JohnMee unfortunately it does not have

Comment: If my answer is helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark icon just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After decompressing the `FreeFileSync_10.18_Linux.tar.gz` file that you downloaded, where did you place the resulting `FreeFileSync_10.18_Linux` folder?

The reason that this app doesn't work, is because the two included .desktop files are incorrect.

Edit both of these two .desktop files using your favorite editor, and change these two lines to correctly reflect the actual path to their binary files:

```
Exec=/home/zenju/Desktop/FFS/Build/FreeFileSync %F
Icon=/home/zenju/Desktop/FFS/Build/Resources/FreeFileSync.png
```

and...

```
Exec=/home/zenju/Desktop/FFS/Build/RealTimeSync %f
Icon=/home/zenju/Desktop/FFS/Build/Resources/RealTimeSync.png
```

If you'd rather just delete this stuff, just delete the `FreeFileSync_10.18_Linux` folder, the .tar.gz file, and any of the included .desktop files that you copied elsewhere.